# Entity Framework many to one relationship - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm new to Entity Framework. I've trying to setup a relationship between two objects but seem to be having some issues doing so.

I have two entities, a Restaurant, and a Check. A restaurant can have many Checks, but a Check only belongs to a singe Restaurant.

```
[Table("Check")]
    public class Check
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CloseDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public Guid EposCheckId { get; set; }
        public decimal TipAmount { get; set; }
        public int TableNumber { get; set; }
        public Guid StaffId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RestaurantId")]
        public Guid RestaurantId { get; set; }

        public virtual Staff memberOfStaff { get; set; }
        public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
        //public ICollection<SalesEntry> SalesEntries { get; set; }

        public string ToJson()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }

[Table("Restaurant")]
    public class Restaurant
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string LoginId { get; set; }
        public string Pin { get; set; }
        public string EposAuthToken { get; set; }
        public int EposBusinessId { get; set; }
        public long EposBusinessLocationId { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan DayEndTime { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationStatus { get; set; }
        public byte[] Logo { get; set; }
        public string LogoContentType { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string MerchantIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string MerchantSecretKey { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Check> Checks { get; set; }
    }
```

In one piece of code I'm retrieving a Check, and then trying to get the Id of the restaurant that the Check belongs to, but in doing so I get the following error;

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The property 'Restaurant' on the Check appears to be null, even though the 'RestaurantId' property on the Check is available.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: So do I need to specifically define what I want to be included? Sorry, I'm coming from a Java/Spring Boot background where annotations handle the relationships. I just assumed everything would be lazy loaded by default?

Comment: Lazy loading is not enabled by default. [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) section from the previous link explains it. Consider reading the whole concept, it's important.

Comment: Thanks, adding the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies packaged and enabling lazy loading as described in that link fixed the problem.